# Can't reach to controller for custom module (Magento 1.9.2.4)

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, controllers, ce-1.9.2.4

I have created one module in **magento 1.9.2.4** and I want to check front end controller is working or not,but get an error **404 Not Found page**.

**Config.xml** (C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\local\Sevenbits\Demo\etc\config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!-- about modules -->
    <modules>
        <Sevenbits_Demo>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Sevenbits_Demo>
    </modules>


    <!-- Setup  class  path for all things -->
    <global>
        <models>
        <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Model</class>
        </demo>
        </models>

        <blocks>
        <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Block</class>
        </demo>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
        <demo>
            <class>Sevenbits_Demo_Helper</class>
        </demo>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <!-- For Frontend Controller-->

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>demo</frontName>
                    <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
                </args>
            </demo>
        <routers>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

**IndexController.php** (C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\code\local\Sevenbits\Demo\controllers\IndexControllers.php)

```
<?php


class Sevenbit_Demo_IndexControllers extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

            echo "Hello World";
    }


}
```

**Sevebits_Demo.xml** (C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\app\etc\modules\Sevenbits_Demo.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sevenbits_Demo>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sevenbits_Demo>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**You can find full source code here :**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PWEkckbXCUNkpQZ2N6eEM3a1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How ur are accessing with URL.provide url

Comment: @PradeepSanku I access thorugh this url :  http://127.0.0.1/shop/index.php/demo/index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change in two files as below in your module,

**1./app/code/local/Sevenbits/Demo/controllers/IndexController.php**
class name is wrong, replace with below code,

```
<?php


class Sevenbits_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

            echo "Hello World";
    }


}
```

**2. config.xml**

```
<!-- For Frontend Controller-->

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <demo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>demo</frontName>
                    <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
                </args>
            </demo>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

Note: After I made this two changes in your module, I am getting below response in my browser when i run url, **http://localhost/magento1924/index.php/demo/index**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFRzNTdGwzYWxFR0k/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

If you replace this bit:

```
      <demo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>Test</frontName>
                <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
            </args>
        </demo>
```

With:

```
      <demo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>demo</frontName>
                <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
            </args>
        </demo>
```

You will be able to access your controller with: http://magentourl.com/demo

If you need to access it with http://magentourl.com/test you ll have to change it to:

```
      <test>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>test</frontName>
                <module>Sevenbits_Demo</module>
            </args>
        </test>
```

Basically the `<frontName>` node needs to match your URL path

On top of that your controller class name is missing an "s" it should be:

```
Sevenbits_Demo_IndexController
```

Also remove the extra "s" after IndexController in both your class name and your file name

Comment: Still get an error 404

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/shop/index.php/demo/index - currently use this url after modification of frontend name

Comment: @VasimVanzara see my edit your class is missing an "s"

Comment: added "s" still same issue is there

Comment: @VasimVanzara see my edit. Remove the "s" after IndexController in both class name and file name

Comment: okay .No still same issue

Comment: Module is here please check : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PWEkckbXCUNkpQZ2N6eEM3a1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VasimVanzara not on a computer right now I'm out of ideas did you try to flush the cache?

Comment: I have already disable cache.